# PHP MySQL IF Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following IF/Else statement:

```
        if ( {$row['Stock']} > 0 ) {
        echo "<div class='col-md-2'>{$row['Stock']}</div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class='col-md-2'>Out of Stock</div>";
        }
```

The {$row['Stock']}  is a field in a MySQL statement. If I just echo the Stock quantity, it will echo the number. However, with my If/Else statement I get nothing on the page at all... is there something wrong with putting that MySQL statement in the PHP If/Else?

Comment: `{$row['Stock']}` is invalid syntax inside an `if` statement, try just `if ( $row['Stock'] > 0 ) {` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out... had to remove the {} from around the $row in the if comparison.

Comment: The variable is already a variable inside the {}. So there's no need to try to get php to echo it out again as if you would inside like a smarty template